# Is it possible to develop a website blog using only HTML5?

Tags: html

How do I go about it? I already have my layout done and want to include a blog page into it. I feel having a CMS will be overkill just for a blog page.

Comment: Your going to need to be more specific. Do you mean a page that has some stories on it and you just update the code to add an item? Or do you want users to sign up and contribute? Either way, just doing it in flat HTML is never going to be ideal. Maybe try WordPress, you can get a blog up and running in a couple of hours.

Comment: Wow. 38 seconds and already 2 down votes. I think you need to explain what it is you're looking for more. If all you're looking for is to make something with HTML (5 or otherwise), and have no preprocessing on the server end (PHP, node.js, etc.) or database, the answer is: Of course! And your website will be blazing fast. But it's gonna be a huge pain to maintain, and I hope, for everyone's sake, that you're the only one doing so.

Comment: Have to agree with @Brad here.using only HTML 5 will give you a static page with minimum interaction (No idea how and what functionalities you would include).. Something like Wordpress is your best bet. I am voting to close this as it is a vague question for the site though

Comment: I am familiar with CMS. Personally, I would prefer using Drupal as a CMS rather than WordPress. But I am thinking it's too much of an overkill especially since I already have my layout just as I want it. I would rather do the manual database just for the blog. Not much shall be changing in terms of content..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMS's will simplify your life greatly.

Sure you can build it all yourself in pure HTML5 and update the code whenever you want to update something.. But it's very bad practice and not recommended. Thats why you're question got down-voted so quickly.. very bad idea.

Have a look at [Anchor](https://anchorcms.com/) & [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) they're quite nice.

Comment: Thank you, I will check them out. CMS would have been too much of an overkill for this project. I will be the one maintaining it. So, saw no point in adding a cms. I just need a light 'blogish feature'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand what you mean by using only html5, but if you just want to avoid using CMS, you will need at least to work on some php & mysql in order to make the content more... dynamic.

Comment: Thank you, that's easier than creating a whole new layout and customizing it to fit a CMS structure.